# Making Table Rows Not Highlight When Clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I created a table that is for viewing purposes only.  The automatic highlighting of any table row that is clicked is a bit unnecessary and misleading.  How do I turn the row highlight on click off?

Comment: you need to call UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle` property to return any of the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` values, which include `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a new cell, set the cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

 return cell;
}
```